# reporting services unpivoting in chart

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm looking to be able to create a report which shows some summary data and full details from the same source.
Sample data is like this:

```
create table #data (id INT,[type] NVARCHAR(30), error1 INT, error2 INT, error3 INT, error4 INT,error5 INT)

INSERT INTO #data values (1,'a',1,0,1,0,1)
INSERT INTO #data values (2,'a',0,0,1,1,0)
INSERT INTO #data values (3,'b',1,1,0,0,0)
INSERT INTO #data values (4,'c',1,1,1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #data values (5,'b',0,0,1,0,1)
INSERT INTO #data values (6,'a',0,0,0,0,1)
```

And what it's showing is for each id and type the number of errors (in fact there are 18 columns of error type and about 40,000 rows of data).

What I want is to be able to show on my report 1) a chart showing for each type the number of each error and 2) a table showing the full details of the errors are.

As it stands I am able to create a horizontal stacked bar chart which shows for each type the number of errors - i.e:

```
A | error1 sum | error2 sum | error3 sum | error4 sum | error5 sum     
B | error1 sum | error2 sum | error3 sum | error4 sum | error5 sum     
C | error1 sum | error2 sum | error3 sum | error4 sum | error5 sum
```

But what I would like to get is:

```
Error1 |  Sum of A  |  Sum of B  |  Sum of C    
Error2 |  Sum of A  |  Sum of B  |  Sum of C    
Error3 |  Sum of A  |  Sum of B  |  Sum of C    
Error4 |  Sum of A  |  Sum of B  |  Sum of C    
Error5 |  Sum of A  |  Sum of B  |  Sum of C
```

And then ideally to be able to sort by the total of A + B + C (descending)?

Hopefully this makes sense - new to reporting services so not sure how the best way to approach this would be - I could rerun my data to output in a different format if it would help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a view to make your data to look more flat (table like)

Eg

```
SELECT type, 'error1' As errorname, error1 AS error
FROM data

UNION ALL

SELECT type, 'error2', error2
FROM data

UNION ALL

....
```

Then make a query that selects from the view

```
SELECT type,errorname, SUM(error) AS error
FROM data
GROUP BY type,errorname
```

You can use the matrix of reporting services to display the data and make charts with any combination you need